# Relation between automatic deletion of copy constructors and assignements

Tags: c++

In our code base we were using this in past:

```
  Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
  Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
  Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
  Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = delete;
```

But as we were discussing it later we came to conclusion it is redundant and just:

```
  Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
  Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
```

Should be enough, because others are deleted automaticaly.

**Is it 100% true even with different compilers and if yes is it possible to reduce it even more to delete for example just one of them and all others are auto deleted?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIR you should delete just copy-part, i.e. Foo(const Foo&) and Foo& operator = (const Foo&); . If copy-part is deleted - and move part is not present  - then move is based on copy - so deleted too. But I have not link to doc to prove that - I bet other will find the correct part of std saying that.

Comment: asking for external ressources is considered off-topic. Don't ask where to find the answer, but ask for the answer ;). I suggest to remove the last 2 sentences, it won't change the question

Comment: Noteworthy: explicitly `=delete`d functions differ from functions that are not defaulted (implicitly synthesized), as per the Howard Hinnant [special members table](https://howardhinnant.github.io/smf.jpg) jpg.  From [Tip of the Week 143](https://abseil.io/tips/143): The deleted function is thus *defined* and *participates in name lookup and overload resolution as any other function*. It’s a special kind of “radioactive” definition which says “don’t touch!”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes and no.**

[Copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) is still generated with user declared copy constructor (or destructor), but this behaviour is deprecated and may be removed in future C++ standard versions.
Any sane compiler should issue a warning if such deprecated behaviour is relied on.

[Move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) will not be implicitly generated if either copy or move constructor is present.

Also, [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) is not generated if you have a copy constructor declared, so

```
Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
```

will be enough. However, it may still be worth to explicitly declare everything as deleted, just to make your intent clear.

Comment: Definitely agree you should just explicitly delete all four. You lose nothing, and gain a ton of clarity.